# In Linux, does the location of an executable affect how the setuid bit is interpreted?

Tags: linux, security, exploit, setuid

In a Linux system, does the permissions of the directory in which a setuid program resides affect how the kernel launches the process? The reason I ask is that when I compiled an identical setuid program in two different directories, it only actually assumed the user permissions in one directory. I compiled it in `/tmp` and `/home/flag03` where `flag03` is the user account that I am attempting to gain access to. When executed from `/tmp` it did not escalate privileges as expected, but it worked under `/home`.

---

Some background on the problem:

I'm working on level 03 of [exploit-exercises.com/nebula](http://exploit-exercises.com/nebula). The exercise requires that you gain access to a `flag03` user account. The exercise is setup so that the `flag03` user is periodically running a cronjob which will allow you to execute a script in a specific directory. My plan was to write a simple bash script which will compile a setuid program that itself launches a bash shell, and then set the setuid bit with `chmod +s`. The idea is that when the setuid program is compiled, it is compiled by user `flag03` via the cronjob. Once this newly compiled program is executed, it will launch a shell as user `flag03`, and that is the goal.

Here is the simple setuid program (l3.c, based on levels 1 + 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  uid_t uid;
  gid_t gid;

  uid = geteuid();
  gid = getegid();

  setresuid(uid,uid,uid);
  setresgid(gid,gid,gid);
  printf("uid: %d\n", getuid());
  printf("gid: %d\n", getgid());
  system("/bin/bash");

  return 0;
}
```

In order for this to work, a bash script compiles the program as user `flag03` and then chmods the setuid bit.

```
#!/bin/bash

#gcc -o /tmp/l3 /tmp/l3.c
#chmod +s,a+rwx /tmp/l3
gcc -o /home/flag03/l3 /tmp/l3.c
chmod +s,a+rwx /home/flag03/l3
```

The executable generated in `/tmp` does not escalate privileges as expected, but the one generated in `/home/flag03` works as expected.

**NOTE** I just created a new bash script to move the version of the setuid program that was compiled in `/tmp` to `/home/flag03`, and then reset the setuid bit. When executed from there, that version worked as well. So it appears to me that the permissions of the directory in which the setuid program resides has some kind of impact with how the process is launch. Maybe this is related to `/tmp` being a somewhat "special" directory?

Thanks for any interest in this long-winded question!

Comment: Can you check the owner of /tmp/l3 and /home/flag03/l3? Are they both have the same owner flag03 or else?

Comment: Your question might be a bit [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for Stack Overflow. It could be better suited for our sister sites, http://security.stackexchange.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @tian_yufeng They both indeed had the same owner, as they were both compiled as the same used (and then chmod'd).

Answer (score 3):

If the filesystem is mounted with the `nosuid` option, the suid bit will be ignored when executing files located there. As I understand it, `/tmp` is usually a separate filesystem (often `tmpfs`) mounted with the `nosuid` option. The motivation for this configuration is preventing a compromised account that has no writable storage except `/tmp` (e.g. `nobody`) from being able to produce suid binaries, which may be used in certain elaborate multi-step attacks to elevate privilege.